# find string in text file from right

Tags: string, vbscript

How do I find a character in a string from right?

here is what I try to do, I have following file path:

```
\\abc\shows\t3rtf\ggh\episodes\111\yuo\character\goodday.jpg
\\abc\shows\gt6yh\ggh\episodes\111\yuo\pop\5656h.jpg
\\abc\shows\gh455g\ghj\episodes\111\yuo\character\bhy74f.jpg
```

I need to print/show the file name only. (goodday.jpg, 5656h.jpg and bhy74f.jpg)

I am thinking finding the "\" from right, then I should be able to print out the file name.

I tried InStrRev, but not good.

```
response.write InStrRev(txt,"\")
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

solve my own problem: mid(txt,InStrRev(txt,"\")+1)